# Given a set of lines, how do I calculate how many triangles they form

Tags: java

When given the following set of coordinates which defines a line segment from point **(x1,y1)** to **(x2,y2)**

```
1.350 1.890 3.825 3.330
3.915 1.575 2.385 3.690
1.350 2.295 4.545 1.845
2.250 1.710 4.140 3.060
2.250 3.150 3.465 1.755
```

You have a **triangle** if you can start at an intersection of line segments **A** and **B**, follow **B** until it intersects with some line segment **C** and then follow **C** until it intersects with **A**.

It seems obvious to me that each line of the input corresponds to a line defined by two points, and because if this I have converted them into five 2D lines using Line2D.Double and storing those 5 lines in an ArrayList.

My issue is actually finding the triangles. 
My initial thought was to find an intersection and then proceed to the intersected line and see if that intersects and then see if the third line intersects with the first.

This is my attempt at doing that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 2; i++) {
  if (list.get(i).intersectsLine(list.get(i + 1))) {
    if (list.get(i+1).intersectsLine(list.get(i + 2))) {
      if (list.get(i+2).intersectsLine(list.get(i))) {
        count++; // Count number of triangles
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However this gives me the answer 3 instead of the correct answer (which is 4).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :-**

```
for(int n = 0;n<list.size(); i++) {
    for(int m = n+1;m<list.size(); m++) {  //m=n+1 : guarantee unique
        for(int k = m+1;k<list.size(); k++) {  //k=m+1 : guarantee unique
            if (
                list.get(n).intersectsLine(list.get(m))  &&
                list.get(m).intersectsLine(list.get(k))  &&
                list.get(n).intersectsLine(list.get(k))  
            ) {
                 amountOfTriangle++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### **Description**

The idea is to find amount of unique tuples `(n,m,k)` that are forming triangle.
The tricky part is to **not** count duplicate ones.
For example `(0,1,2)` is the same triangle as `(0,2,1)` - should not be counted twice.
Therefore, I added `m=n+1` and `k=m+1` to guarantee uniqueness.

### **Further improvement**

Note that this solution is just a draft.
If you are a perfectionist, you may also:-

- optimize it a bit (e.g. move some statements outside innest loop)
- check some edge cases e.g. 3 lines not intersect at the same point.

Please let me know whether it works.

Comment: @intact28 Yay!   .... you can press the green "correct" mark at my solution.  It will +15 my rep, +2 your rep, and mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample program for you.  This programs takes some points, find the distinct points, and then uses those points to plot triangles.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class DrawTriangle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //I changed the points to make processing easier. I also add 100 to each point so that the output looks better.
        String[] points = {"100.350:100.890", "300.825:300.330", "300.915:100.575", "200.385:300.690", 
                           "100.350:200.295", "400.545:100.845", "200.250:100.710", "400.140:300.060",
                           "200.250:300.150", "300.465:100.755"};

        Set<String> distinctPoints = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(points));//Keep only distinct points
        List<String> distincePointsList = new ArrayList<String>(distinctPoints); //Make the distinct points gettable


        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Press me!");


        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for(int i = 0; i < distincePointsList.size() - 3; i++)
                {
                    for(int t = i + 1; t < distincePointsList.size() - 2; t++)
                    {
                        for(int s = t + 1; s < distincePointsList.size() - 1; s++)
                        {
                            root.getChildren().addAll(drawTriangle(distincePointsList.get(i), distincePointsList.get(t), distincePointsList.get(s))); //get the three points and return a triangle made by the lines drawn from point to point
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1080, 720);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    //Creates drawing of lines that form triangle. returns an list of the 3 lines
    static List drawTriangle(String p1, String p2, String p3)
    {
        List<Line> lineHolder = new ArrayList();
        String[] tempP1 = p1.split(":");
        String[] tempP2 = p2.split(":");
        String[] tempP3 = p3.split(":");

        Line line1 = new Line();
        line1.setStartX(Float.parseFloat(tempP1[0]));
        line1.setStartY(Float.parseFloat(tempP1[1]));
        line1.setEndX(Float.parseFloat(tempP2[0]));
        line1.setEndY(Float.parseFloat(tempP2[1]));
        lineHolder.add(line1);

        Line line2 = new Line();
        line2.setStartX(Float.parseFloat(tempP2[0]));
        line2.setStartY(Float.parseFloat(tempP2[1]));
        line2.setEndX(Float.parseFloat(tempP3[0]));
        line2.setEndY(Float.parseFloat(tempP3[1]));
        lineHolder.add(line2);

        Line line3 = new Line();
        line3.setStartX(Float.parseFloat(tempP3[0]));
        line3.setStartY(Float.parseFloat(tempP3[1]));
        line3.setEndX(Float.parseFloat(tempP1[0]));
        line3.setEndY(Float.parseFloat(tempP1[1]));
        lineHolder.add(line3);

        return lineHolder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow you put a lot of effort into this!   Do you know how to run it online somewhere?     I know only ideone and coliru but it works only for C++.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a lot of effort

Comment: I am not sure if there is a place to run JavaFx code online.

Comment: You have Java as a tag. So I am guessing you are using Java Swing or JavaFx. This code is written in JavaFx. If you have the latest version of Netbeans you can recreate this program.

Comment: Also I see you have a variable to count the number of triangle. I missed that part, but add a counter variable and increment it after calling drawTriangle();